# Kotlin Unit Testing for Function Parameter and Object

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, kotlin

In Kotlin,, we could have function object and pass in as function parameter.

1. How to create unit test to test the function object logic? (e.g. `funcParam` below)
2. How to unit test the function that has function parameter? (e.g. `functionWithFuncParam` below) - i.e. can I create a Mock for `funcParam`?

   ```
   class MyClass1(val myObject: MyObject) {
       val funcParam = fun (num: Int): Int {
           return num * num
       }

       fun myFunctionOne() {
           myObject.functionWithFuncParam(funcParam)
       }
   }

   class MyObject () {
       fun functionWithFuncParam(funcParam: (Int) -> Int) {
           println(funcParam(32))
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `funcParam` is `public` intentionally you can test it as any other method:

```
class MyClass1Tests {
    val sut = MyClass1(MyObject())

    @Test
    fun `funcParam multiplies input`() {
        assertThat(sut.funcParam(4), equalTo(16))
        assertThat(sut.funcParam(1), equalTo(1))
        assertThat(sut.funcParam(0), equalTo(0))
        assertThat(sut.funcParam(-10), equalTo(100))
    }
}
```

If `funcParam` is private you shouldn't test its behavior directly but only through public interface of it's containing class.

When testing `functionWithFuncParam` you can easily supply a stub implementation of `(Int) -> Int`:

```
class MyObjectTests {
    val outContent = ByteArrayOutputStream().apply {
        System.setOut(PrintStream(this))
    }
    val sut = MyObject()
    @Test
    fun `functionWithFuncParam prints function output `() {
        sut.functionWithFuncParam { 12345678  }
        assertThat(outContent.toString(), containsString("12345678"))
    }
}
```

If you'd like to test `MyClass1` interaction with `MyObject` one way is to use interface implemented `MyObject` by in `MyClass1`. Usually the best choice if 2 classes are distinct collaborators in a sense that they have separate mostly unrelated behaviour:

```
interface FunctionalObj {
    fun functionWithFuncParam(funcParam: (Int) -> Int)
}
class MyClass1(val myObject: FunctionalObj) {
//omitted for brevity
}
class MyClass1Tests {
    var params = mutableListOf<(Int)->Int>()
    val sut = MyClass1(object: FunctionalObj {
        override fun functionWithFuncParam(funcParam: (Int) -> Int) { params.add(funcParam) }
    })

    @Test
    fun `myFunctionOne calls delegate`() {
        sut.myFunctionOne()
        assertThat(params.size, equalTo(1))
        assertThat(params[0], equalTo(sut.funcParam))//only if `funcParam` is public
    }
}
```

If `MyClass1` and `MyObject` interaction is more complex (i.e. involves more calls both [queries and commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)) it would imply that they are peers working together closely. In such case, using mocks can lead to brittle and hard to write tests.

Comment: Thanks miensol. I'm thinking of if I am mocking myObject, and want to test that `myFunctionOne` to verify it is calling `functionWithFuncParam`, is there a way I could supply "any()" for the Function Param?

Comment: @Elye see my update. What is passed to `myObject` appears to me like an implementation detail - and it's generally a bad idea to rely on them in tests. One not test their behavior together and not rely on mocks?